# Significado de => en una funcion

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo la siguiente función.

```
function todosIguales(array) {
   
   return array.every(v => v == array[0]);
}
```

¿Qué significa `=>` entre las dos *v* para este caso?.

Gracias.